# shutil.copy() files with multiple and code edited parameters

Tags: python, copy, multiple-variable-return

I'm trying to copy files from 3 parent paths to child paths of different names and i'm struggling to get it to perform the final part of the puzzle! I have 2 lists:

Cust relate to and are relevant per num:

Joe = 010

Bob (parent name) = 016

Mark = 018

John (child of bob) = 016

Peter (Child of Bob) = 016

I've managed to get my code to check if a filepath exists in the source folders and if it doesnt then replace John or Peter (children) with Bob (Parent). It correctly returns the file paths.

```
def copyFiles(cust_list, proj_num):
    cust_list = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mark', 'John', 'Peter']
    proj_num = ['010', '016', '018']    
    for cust, num in zip(cust_list, proj_num):
        source = f'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_{num} ({cust})/01_Docs_Issued/'
        dest = f'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_{cust}/Data/'

        if not os.path.exists(source):
        
            new_cust = cust.replace(cust, 'Bob')
            source = source.replace(cust, new_cust)
        
        print(source)
```

output

```
'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_010 (Joe)/01_Docs_Issued/'
'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_016 (Bob)/01_Docs_Issued/'
'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_018 (Mark)/01_Docs_Issued/'
'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_016 (Bob)/01_Docs_Issued/'
'C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/Live_016 (Bob)/01_Docs_Issued/'
```

What I cant get it to do afterwards is copy a file from each Source folder which contains a specific string in filename and extension (.pdf) to each of the dest paths above per customer name in the destination.
I'm expecting to copy the file to the following locations.

```
C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_Joe/Data/'
C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_Bob/Data/'
C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_Mark/Data/'
C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_John/Data/'
C:/Users/Desktop/Automation_Testing/new_Peter/Data/'
```

I've tried many variations of `for`, `if` and I just cant it to copy the files across.

```
for file in os.listdir(source):
            
            if 'INVOICE' in file.upper():
                file_type = '.pdf'
                if file_type == True:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), dest)
print(os.path.join(dest, file))
```

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for any questions or advice.

Comment: Sorry, buts it does not make sense. Your explanation of the problem is not sufficient for me, I did not understand what was the problem. Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or use debugging techniques to find the source of the problem ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I'm sorry it's not clear, it's a little hard to explain. Basically i'm trying to move a file from each of the parent folders to the child folders based on the customer list. But if the cust name is not in the parent folder then replace the child name with the parent name and copy the file. Thank you for trying to understand. I'll keep plugging away and see if i can work it out.